# Application is not working on launching from apps

Tags: android, webview, launcher

i have developed a simple android application, to show a web like `Google`. It is working fine, when launch from eclipse, does not work when relaunch from installed apps of emulator.
Here is my `WebView` activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my .xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How it's not working?

Comment: Do you mean when you click on the app icon on the emulator, the app isn't launching? Or does it crash?

Comment: Connect the device to desktop and in log cat, check the logs and post it here.

Comment: @EmbattledSwag when i click on app icon on the emulator, it only show the activity without webview, it does not crash.

Comment: @prem sorry! but i can not understand, what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}


@Override
protected void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();
         WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Therefore, it launches first time when i launch from eclipse.